# Trying to remove only the characters F or C following numbers

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm trying to find a regex (that will work in node.js) to remove the Fahrenheit and Celsius letters and replace them with " degrees" from the below weather forecast string.

"Clear skies. Low 46F. NNW winds shifting to ENE at 10 to 15 mph."

I want the above string to read as below:

"Clear skies. Low 46 degrees. NNW winds shifting to ENE at 10 to 15 mph."

There could be more than one instance of a temperature in the string.

NOTE: I only want to remove the F or C if it's immediately following a number with no space in-between. If "Florida" were in the above string, I'd want the letter "F" left untouched.

I've tried the below regex, but it finds the entire 46F. I just want it changed to 46 degrees.

```
/\d+[FC]/g
```

Thanks.

Comment: Capture a number and replace with `$1 degrees`

Comment: Thanks, but jode.js is treating the $1 as a literal:

speechOutput = speechOutput.replace(/\d+[FC]/g, '$1 degrees');

If I put it outside the single quotes, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the lack of the capturing group (parentheses):

Use this:

```
/(\d+)[FC]/g
```

`$1` means the first capturing group. The `\d+` in this case.

```
speechOutput = speechOutput.replace(/(\d+)[FC]/g, '$1 degrees');
```

Comment: @KevinKey Almost... you can accept the answer too and grab a couple points too  